# Array.toString(boolean) values

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine, servlets

In java servlet,

```
boolean[] arrBool = new boolean[6];
```

I am showing `resp.getWriter.println(Arrays.toString(arrBool))`.

So output is like `[false, true, true, false, false, true]`.

I am generating these boolean values randomly. Is there any way I can show true values in different color, or style or something to distinguish with false ones?

Comment: I don't have JSP page, this is servlet

Comment: Add a loop to write true and false in different html/css style.

Answer (score 1):

Try surrounding it with `span`

```
resp.getWriter().println(
        Arrays.toString(arrBool).replace(
                "true","<span style=\"color:#0000FF\">true</span>"));
```

You can also simply iterate over array and if you find `true` print it as `<span style=\"color:#0000FF\">true</span>`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It replaces "true" but doesn't recognize HTML. It just shows whatever is there, like, <span style=\"color:#0000FF\">true</span>

Comment: @Mac Normally output from servlets is HTML code that is used by browser so it should work. Could you tell more about how you are using this code?

Comment: I am using this code to run on google app engine and then retrieving these values on android app. I checked again, it is just showing exact thing in the replace

Comment: @Mac Oh, so the output is not used by browser but by android app. In that case my answer wont work. Unfortunately I know almost nothing about android components. Maybe if you post code from your android app that uses output from servlet and prints it we would be able to figure out something. Without it I won't be able to help you.